# Удаление родительского элемента в JS

Tags: javascript, html, css

Есть такой список фильмов , у всех элементов **li** имеется **div.delete** - через **CSS** превратил их в кнопки с иконкой корзины, когда нажимаешь на них элемент li должен удалиться из списка и вот мой кусок кода HTML:

```js
const deleteList = document.querySelectorAll('.delete');

deleteList.forEach((btn, i) => {
  btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
    btn.parentElement.remove();
    movieDB.movies.splice(i, 1);
  });
});
```

```html
<div class="promo__interactive">
  <div>
    <div class="promo__interactive-title">ПРОСМОТРЕННЫЕ ФИЛЬМЫ</div>
    <ul class="promo__interactive-list">
      <li class="promo__interactive-item">ЛОГАН
        <div class="delete">X</div>
      </li>
      <li class="promo__interactive-item">ЛИГА СПРАВЕДЛИВОСТИ
        <div class="delete">X</div>
      </li>
      <li class="promo__interactive-item">ЛА-ЛА ЛЭНД
        <div class="delete">X</div>
      </li>
      <li class="promo__interactive-item">ОДЕРЖИМОСТЬ
        <div class="delete">X</div>
      </li>
      <li class="promo__interactive-item">СКОТТ ПИЛИГРИМ ПРОТИВ...
        <div class="delete">X</div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Первым делом через **JS** передал в переменную **deleteList** все **div.delete** [5 штук]

Потом перебирая эти элементы в **deleteList** , создаю событие на все **div.delete**, где после клика удаляю родительский элемент **li**

Но почему-то ничего не удаляется, где я упустил?
Что не так?))

Comment: Приведенный код, определенно, работает. Если что-то не удаляется - смотри либо ошибки в консоли браузера, либо проверяй действительно ли идет клик по нужному элементу.

Comment: `<div class="delete">ЛА-ЛА ЛЭНД</div>` содержание добавьте в "кнопки", иначе они не имеют  высоты и по ним невозможно попасть.

Comment: @Leonid Если только высота не устанавливается стилями.

Comment: Если при работающем коде не работает, то скорее всего именно потому, в кнопки не попадается.

Comment: Всем спасибо, я целый день пытался, в итоге переписал код, он работает только если в функцию положить всё.
Честно не понимаю, почему вот так ,как написано было не работает, уже мозги вытекли, но спасибо большое,  хоть узнал, что был рабочий))

Answer (score 1):

Код отрабатывает без ошибок

```js
const movieDB={
 movies:[
   'ЛИГА СПРАВЕДЛИВОСТИ',
   'ЛА-ЛА ЛЭНД',
   'ОДЕРЖИМОСТЬ',
   'СКОТТ ПИЛИГРИМ ПРОТИВ...'
 ]
} 

const deleteList = document.querySelectorAll('.delete');
deleteList.forEach((btn, i) => {
    btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
    btn.parentElement.remove();
        movieDB.movies.splice(i, 1);
    });
});
```

```css
.delete{
  display: inline;
}
.delete::after{
  content: "❌"
}
```

```html
<div class="promo__interactive">
    <div>
        <div class="promo__interactive-title">ПРОСМОТРЕННЫЕ ФИЛЬМЫ</div>
        <ul class="promo__interactive-list">
            <li class="promo__interactive-item">ЛОГАН
                <div class="delete"></div>
            </li>
            <li class="promo__interactive-item">ЛИГА СПРАВЕДЛИВОСТИ
                <div class="delete"></div>
            </li>
            <li class="promo__interactive-item">ЛА-ЛА ЛЭНД
                <div class="delete"></div>
            </li>
            <li class="promo__interactive-item">ОДЕРЖИМОСТЬ
                <div class="delete"></div>
            </li>
            <li class="promo__interactive-item">СКОТТ ПИЛИГРИМ ПРОТИВ...
                <div class="delete"></div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
<div>
```

Comment: Спасибо, дружище!